# Resetting Baseline Level of Predictor Variable in svyglm Function

Tags: r

I am using the survey package in R for modeling with complex survey data.  I am trying to reset the baseline level of certain predictor variables being used in a logistic regression without success.
The following is a reproducible example:

```
library(RCurl)
library(survey)
data <- getURL("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/cbenjamin1821/careertech-  ed/master/elsq1adj.csv")
elsq1ch <- read.csv(text = data)
#Specifying the svyrepdesign object which applies the BRR weights
elsq1ch_brr<-svrepdesign(variables = elsq1ch[,1:16], repweights = elsq1ch[,18:217], weights = elsq1ch[,17], combined.weights = TRUE, type = "BRR")
elsq1ch_brr
#Log. Reg. model
allCC <- svyglm(formula=F3ATTAINB~F1PARED+BYINCOME+F1RACE+F1SEX+F1RGPP2+F1HIMATH+F1RTRCC,family="binomial",design=elsq1ch_brr,subset=BYSCTRL==1&G10COHRT==1,na.action=na.omit)
summary(allCC)
##Attempting to reset baseline level for predictor variable to "PreAlg or Less"; the baseline level in the model is currently "Adv Alg"
#Both attempts did not work
elsq1ch$F1HIMATH <- C(elsq1ch$F1HIMATH,contr.treatment, base=1)
elsq1ch$F1HIMATH <- relevel(elsq1ch$F1HIMATH,"PreAlg or Less")
#Log. Reg. model with no changes in baseline levels for the predictor
allCC <- svyglm(formula=F3ATTAINB~F1PARED+BYINCOME+F1RACE+F1SEX+F1RGPP2+F1HIMATH+F1RTRCC,family="binomial",design=elsq1ch_brr,subset=BYSCTRL==1&G10COHRT==1,na.action=na.omit)
summary(allCC)
```

Any guidance is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Anthony Damico provided me with this approach that worked:
    elsq1ch_brr <- update( elsq1ch_brr , F1HIMATH = relevel(F1HIMATH,"PreAlg or Less") )